# Restore checkbox state in custom array adapter

Tags: android, checkbox, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

I'm trying to set my app so that when I kill the task and restart the app that the right check boxes will still be checked. It seems to be okay when the app goes to the background, but when its fully existed all the check boxes are blank. I've tried a few things but can't seem to get it to work. Here's my code.

```
 public class SyncHomeFragment extends ListFragment {

    ListView listView;
    Button button;
    ArrayAdapterWithCheck adapter;
    boolean checkedState;

    @Override public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_sync_home, container, false);

        button = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.confirm_button);

        adapter = new ArrayAdapterWithCheck(getActivity(), getModel());
        setListAdapter(adapter);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //TODO for test only remove
                boolean [] items =  adapter.getCheckBoxState();
                for(Boolean b : items){
                    /*String item = Boolean.toString(b);
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getBaseContext(), item, 0).show();*/
                    List<CheckedModel> checkedModels = adapter.getList();
                    String item = checkedModels.get(1).getName();
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getBaseContext(), item, 0).show();
                }
            }
        });

        return rootView;
    }

    @Override public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        boolean[] itemStates = adapter.getCheckBoxState();
        savedInstanceState.putBooleanArray("CheckBoxState", itemStates);
    }

    @Override public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        if(savedInstanceState != null) {
            boolean[] checkedState = savedInstanceState.getBooleanArray("CheckBoxState");
            adapter.setCheckBoxState(checkedState);
        }
    }

    private List<CheckedModel> getModel() {
        List<CheckedModel> list = new ArrayList<CheckedModel>();
        list.add(get("Linux"));
        list.add(get("Windows7"));
        list.add(get("Suse"));
        list.add(get("Eclipse"));
        list.add(get("Ubuntu"));
        list.add(get("Solaris"));
        list.add(get("Android"));
        list.add(get("iPhone"));

        return list;
    }

    private CheckedModel get(String s) {
        return new CheckedModel(s);
    }

}
```

My Array Adapter

```
public class ArrayAdapterWithCheck extends ArrayAdapter<CheckedModel> {

    private final List<CheckedModel> list;
    private final Activity context;
    private boolean [] checkBoxState;
    private ViewHolder viewHolder;

    public ArrayAdapterWithCheck(Activity context, List<CheckedModel> list) {
        super(context, R.layout.row_layout_with_check, list);
        this.context = context;
        this.list = list;
        checkBoxState = new boolean[list.size()];
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        protected ImageView image;
        protected TextView text;
        protected CheckBox checkbox;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = null;
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflator = context.getLayoutInflater();
            view = inflator.inflate(R.layout.row_layout_with_check, null);
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.image = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.icon);
            viewHolder.text = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.label);

            viewHolder.checkbox = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.check);
            viewHolder.checkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                    CheckedModel element = (CheckedModel) viewHolder.checkbox.getTag();
                    element.setSelected(buttonView.isChecked());
                    checkBoxState[position] = isChecked;

                    //save(list.get(position), checkBoxState[position]);
                    String item = Boolean.toString(checkBoxState[position]);
                    //TODO Remove
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), item, 0).show();
                }
            });
            viewHolder.checkbox.setChecked(checkBoxState[position]);
            view.setTag(viewHolder);
            viewHolder.checkbox.setTag(list.get(position));
        } else {
            view = convertView;
            ((ViewHolder) view.getTag()).checkbox.setTag(list.get(position));
        }
        ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        holder.text.setText(list.get(position).getName());
        holder.checkbox.setChecked(list.get(position).isSelected());
        return view;
    }

    public List<CheckedModel> getList() {
        return list;
    }

    public boolean[] getCheckBoxState() {
        return checkBoxState;
    }


    public void setCheckBoxState(boolean[] checkBoxState) {
        this.checkBoxState = checkBoxState;
        for(int i = 0; i<checkBoxState.length; i++){
            viewHolder.checkbox.setChecked(checkBoxState[i]);
        }
    }

}
```

My Model

```
public class CheckedModel extends BasicModel {

    private boolean selected;

    public CheckedModel(String name) {
        super(name);
        selected = false;
    }

    public boolean isSelected() {
        return selected;
    }

    public void setSelected(boolean selected) {
        this.selected = selected;
    }
}
```

Is there a way to to restore the state of each checkbox after the app is killed and restored? From looking around I thought using onSaveInstanceState and onActivityCreated but it seems like one or both aren't being called

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`onSaveInstanceState` is useful for when you need to recover from a configuration change, a low memory state, a long time in the background, etc.  But if you actually kill the task and restart the app, you will need a persistent storage mechanism.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

SQLite might be what you are looking for with your CheckedModel; a single table with a name field and a boolean checked field. But this is by no means the only way to do so.

The way you are doing the persistence, using `onSaveInstanceState` and `onActivityCreated`, is absolutely correct for persisting data inside your application. As long as your application is running (even if it has been placed into the background), it can use this to recover the CheckedModel. But if you want that data persisted outside of your application, like if you exit the app and come back, kill the task, restart the device, etc. then you will need to use an external persistent data storage mechanism like those described above.

Comment: Is it better to have both methods to cater for both scenarios or should I just have a external persistent data storage mechanism for when the app is put to the background ect and when it is killed ect ?

Comment: @Unem I think if you have the external one, you don't need the other.  Just one should be good.